# How to create an "On<T1>" event similiar to "HubConnection.On<T1>" in C#

Tags: c#, events

I have a scenario where I need to create an event the exact same way as Microsoft did in HubConnection.On event ([HubConnectionExtension.On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnectionextensions.on?view=aspnetcore-7.0)). I don't know the syntax how to achive this and how to invoke this method in my own implementation.

***Pseudo C# code sample of usage***:

```
ProxyClient client = new();
MyClass1 class1 = new();
MyClass2 class2 = new();

client.On<MessageClass1>(class1.ProcessMessage);
client.On<MessageClass2>(class2.ProcessMessage);
```

where "ProcessMessage" is defined as a method in MyClass1 like this: `public void ProcessMessage(MessageClass1 message) { ... }` and in MyClass2 like this: `public void ProcessMessage(MessageClass2 message) { ... }`

So I need to know how to create this "**On**" event in ProxyClient class and it should be generic T without hard coding the MessageClass1 and MessageClass2.

Comment: You know events? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event. Where exactly is your problem in implementing them?

Comment: I need a sample code that shows how to create an event which then can be used as I described in the pseudo code. I know events but don't know the syntax how to implement an event the way I would use it as I described: client.On<T>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in C# `event` functionality won't work for this because you want to subscribe to multiple events of different types; so we'll need to implement the adding, storing and calling of these events manually.

```
class ProxyClient
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>> _messageHandlers = new();
    
    public void On<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        if(!_messageHandlers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out List<Delegate>? handlers))
        {
            handlers = new List<Delegate>();
            _messageHandlers.Add(typeof(T), handlers);
        }
        
        handlers.Add(action);
    }
    
    public void ProcessMessage<T>(T message)
    {
        if(_messageHandlers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out List<Delegate>? handlers))
        {
            foreach(Delegate handler in handlers)
            {
                Action<T>? typedHandler = handler as Action<T>;
                typedHandler?.Invoke(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`_messageHandlers` stores the event handlers, each message type can have multiple handlers.

`On` will first try to get any existing handlers for the type `T`, if there are  existing handler the new handler will be added to the exiting list, otherwise a new list of handlers is created for the type.

`ProcessMessage` gets any handlers for the type `T` and calls them in order that they were added.

[Try it online.](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

If you're interested in the exact implementation of `HubConnectionHandler.On` you can find the source code [here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core/HubConnectionExtensions.cs).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. So this is not an even rather a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
public class ProxyClient
{
    public void On<T>(Action<T> message) { }
}
```